# How to provide data for Laravel Horizon exception context?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-horizon

When my job fails, Horizon will log the exception but it does not log any data inside that exception, so since my exception is made like this:

```
class ExecutionFailedException extends RuntimeException
{
    private string $server;
    private string $command;
    private string $stdout;
    private string $stderr;

    public function __construct(string $server, string|array $command, string $stdout = '', string $stderr = '', int $code = 0)
    {
        parent::__construct('Failed to execute command on remote server.', $code);

        $this->server = $server;
        $this->command = is_array($command) ? implode("\n", $command) : $command;
        $this->stdout = $stdout;
        $this->stderr = $stderr;
    }

    public function getServer(): string
    {
        return $this->server;
    }

    public function getCommand(): string
    {
        return $this->command;
    }

    public function getStdout(): string
    {
        return $this->stdout;
    }

    public function getStderr(): string
    {
        return $this->stderr;
    }
}
```

The issue is, that horizon gives me no info about the exception other than:

```
Acme\ServerPool\Exceptions\ExecutionFailedException: Failed to execute command on remote server. in /var/www/foo/vendor/acme/server-pool/src/PendingServer.php:35
```

and a stacktrace.

I saw horizon has a field called `Exception Context` that is always `null`.
Is there a way to tell horizon to show the other fields of the exception (stdout, stderr etc.) in that field?

Comment: How do you throw or bind that exception?

Comment: @mrhm I just throw it inside the handle method:
```
if (!$process->isSuccessful()) {
  throw new ExecutionFailedException($this->server, $command, $process->getOutput(), $process->getErrorOutput());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to dig in Horizon's source code and found it:

```
                    'context' => method_exists($exception, 'context')
                        ? json_encode($exception->context())
                        : null,
```

In other words: The exception itself must have a `context()` method.